# Como creo una solicitud HTTP utilizando multipart/form-data con http.client en python3?

Tags: python-3.x, formularios, http

Quiero hacer una solicitud utilizando el header Content-Type: "multipart/form-data".
Quiero pasar de url encoded:

```
uuid="../../tmp"&tokenCSRF="????????"&images="123123"
```

a multipart/form-data utilizando http.client

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Perdón, es mi primera pregunta y la hice de urgencia.